# Java's SHA-256 sometimes returns 255 bits

Tags: java, hash, biginteger, sha

I'm encountering some weird behavior when I use Java's `MessageDigest` to compute the  SHA-256 hash of a `BigInteger`. It appears that sometimes the hash value has 256 bits, but sometimes it has only 255 bits. This is the code that I'm using to test BigInteger hashing:

```
@Test
public void testSHA256LengthConsistent() {
    MessageDigest sha256 = null;
    try {
        sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Assert.fail("NoSuchAlgorithmException. Can't construct the MessageDigest.");
    }
    BigInteger[] tests = {new BigInteger("15902493"), new BigInteger("5189087324092341824"), new BigInteger("7153293421609183203421127438153268")};
    for(BigInteger testNum : tests) {
        byte[] hash = sha256.digest(testNum.toByteArray());
        Assert.assertEquals(32, hash.length); //256 bits is 32 bytes
        BigInteger hashedInt = new BigInteger(1, hash);
        Assert.assertEquals(256, hashedInt.bitLength());
    }
}
```

(Yes, I'm using JUnit 4). This test fails on the third test number, where the second assert fails with "Expected 256 but was 255."

Is there something wrong with the way I'm converting BigIntegers to and from byte arrays? All of the examples I can find for Java's MessageDigest use it to hash Strings, not BigIntegers, so I don't know if there's a "standard" way to use BigIntegers with MessageDigest. Alternatively, is this a bug or edge case in the way Java does SHA-256, and there's something with 7153293421609183203421127438153268 (a number I generated randomly) that results in an off-by-one error in the hash?

By the way, I've already tried converting the hash to a negative BigInteger (using `new BigInteger(-1, hash)`) to see if it was a problem with the sign bit, but I get the exact same result.

Comment: If the top bit is a 0 is it still counted?

Comment: Have you tried printing the offending hashes to see if that provides any insight?

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, but I couldn't see any difference. This is what I got: `Hash of 5189087324092341824 is 109496220347861686136035590056103548957014747448513705676776471153473787201110; 256 bits`
`Hash of 7153293421609183203421127438153268 is 39469060478954654750687726231416937199935884942218059502044137508701079982846; 255 bits`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leading zeros are ignored

```
byte[] bytes = {0x0, 0x1};
System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, bytes).bitLength());
```

prints

```
1
```

not 16 as you appear to expect.

---

I should have read the Javadoc because it states in [BigInteger.bitLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength%28%29)

> number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this BigInteger, excluding a sign bit.

Comment: Yes, and I recommend deleting this test. Don't test the platform. If you don't trust the hashing algorithm to give you the right number of bits how can you trust it to give you the right hash? You have to stop somewhere or you will go crazy.

Comment: I read that Javadoc too, but I didn't understand that it meant leading zeros are ignored. I don't know what a "minimal" two's complement representation is (though I know what two's complement is).

Comment: @JohnWatts I only wrote this test because I wrote a function that should generate a fixed-bit-length number from a SHA-256 hash, and tests on that function were failing with inconsistent bit lengths, so I wanted to isolate the problem.

Comment: "Minimal" here means that the most significant bit is always a 1 unless the number is non-negative. If the number is non-negative you need to add one more zero bit to make sure the number won't be interpreted as negative when read back.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to run a sufficient number of random tests, you would have seen that about half the results are 256 bits long, a quarter 255 bits long, one in eight 254 bits long etc. The reason is that each of the bits of the hash is effectively random, so there is a 50% probability that the high order bit (or, to be precise, any other specific bit you care to look at) is 1 and 50% that it is 0, and 25% probability that the two high order bits (or any other two specific bits you care to look at) are 00 (or any other value you care to test for) and so on.

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int[] bits = new int[257];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        final MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        final BigInteger testNum = new BigInteger(100, random);
        final byte[] hash = sha256.digest(testNum.toByteArray());
        final BigInteger hashedInt = new BigInteger(1, hash);
        bits[hashedInt.bitLength()]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        if (bits[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println(i + " / " + bits[i]);
        }
    }        
}
```

produced:

Bits: 244 Count: 2 0.02%
Bits: 245 Count: 3 0.03%
Bits: 246 Count: 4 0.04%
Bits: 247 Count: 7 0.07%
Bits: 248 Count: 20 0.2%
Bits: 249 Count: 33 0.33%
Bits: 250 Count: 70 0.7%
Bits: 251 Count: 168 1.68%
Bits: 252 Count: 296 2.96%
Bits: 253 Count: 657 6.57%
Bits: 254 Count: 1238 12.38%
Bits: 255 Count: 2510 25.1%
Bits: 256 Count: 4992 49.92%